# Ler e alterar estado de pino GPIO do RaspBerry Pi 3

Tags: php, javascript, raspberry-pi

Estou a fazer um pequeno projecto com um rRspBerry Pi 3 que consiste, entre outras coisas, controlar algumas saídas através de uma página web. Precisava de conseguir saber e imprimir na página qual o estado dessas saídas em determinado instante. Tenho, por exemplo, um botão para ligar um LED e outro botão para desligar, mas preciso de imprimir numa caixa de texto se o LED está ligado ou desligado e deixar, ou não, ligar ou desligar o LED dependendo do seu estado.

Para ler o estado posso usar a função `exec("gpio read ".$i, $status);` em que `$i` é o pino que quero ler e `$status` é onde guarda o estado do pino, mas não sei como incluir isso na minha página web, alguém sabe como fazer ou sabe onde posso consultar um exemplo?

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>




    </head>
    <body>




        <article>  
            <div id="Janelas">
            <h1>Sistemas de Climatização</h1>

            <p>Soalho radiante</p>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#ligar').click(function(){

var a= new XMLHttpRequest();

a.open("GET", "soalholigar.php"); a.onreadystatechange=function(){

if(a.readyState==4){ if(a.status ==200){

 } else alert ("http error"); } }

a.send();

});

});

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#desligar').click(function(){

var a= new XMLHttpRequest();

a.open("GET", "soalhodesligar.php"); a.onreadystatechange=function(){

if(a.readyState==4){ if(a.status ==200){

 } else alert ("http error"); } }

a.send();

});

});



</script>

                <input type="button" id="ligar" value="Ligar">
                <input type="button" id="desligar" value="Desligar">
                <center>


                <input type="text" size="5" name="textgol" value="0">
                </center>


            <p>ZONA 2.</p>

                <input type="button" name="botao-ligar" value="Ligar">
                <input type="button" name="botao-desligar" value="Desligar">

            <p>ZONA 3.</p>

                <input type="button" name="botao-ligar" value="Ligar">
                <input type="button" name="botao-desligar" value="Desligar">

            <p>ZONA 4.</p>

<input type="button" name="botao-ligar" value="Ligar">
                <input type="button" name="botao-desligar" value="Desligar">

            <br/>
            <br/>
            <a href="javascript:window.history.go(-1)">Voltar</a>





    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **1)** Se estás a utilizar jQuery, por quê não efetua as chamadas assíncronas através de `$.ajax`? **2)** O estado do LED poderá ser alterado através de outras fontes ou a interface será a única a controlá-lo? **3)** Qual é o retorno, no terminal, quando você executa o comando `gpio` diretamente?

Comment: 1) Estou a utilizar jQuery mas pela primeira vez, não tenho experiência nem grande conhecimento na matéria. 2) o estado do led pode ser alterado por mais duas interfaces, daí a dificuldade, porque se apenas fosse alterado na interface web podia criar uma varável para guardar o estado. 3) Quando executo gpio write pino estado, não obtenho nenhum retorno no terminal, mas o pino altera o estado.

Comment: Sobre o retorno do comando, me referia ao `gpio read`, para saber como tratar a resposta.

Comment: se fizer gpio read diretamente no terminal retorna 0 ou 1, consoante o estado do pino.

Answer (score 1):

Podemos imaginar dois arquivos PHP: `read.php`, que lerá o estado atual do pino, retornando o valor em JSON, e `write.php`, que alterará o estado do pino.

**read.php**

Podemos imaginar que a resposta JSON deste arquivo seja no formato `{pin: 1, status: 0}`, indicando qual o pino lido e qual o seu estado atual. Como desejamos obter o estado do nosso servidor, esse arquivo tratará uma requisição GET, recebendo como parâmetro o número do pino a ser lido. Ficaria algo assim:

```
<?php

// read.php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$pin = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pin', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

exec("gpio read {$pin}", $status);

$status = (int) $status;

echo json_encode(['pin' => $pin, 'status' => $status]);
```

Assim, ao fazer uma requisição para a URL `read.php?pin=1`, por exemplo, teria o retorno esperado: `{pin: 1, status: 0}`.

Com jQuery, você pode efetuar tal requisição através de `$.get`:

```
$.get('read.php', {pin: 1}, function (data) {
    console.log("O LED está " + (data.status == 0 ? "desligado" : "ligado"));
}, 'json');
```

Ao executar esse código, apareceria no `console` a mensagem:

```
O LED está ligado
```

Caso o retorno do PHP tenha sido `status = 1`, por exemplo.

Se você quiser, por exemplo, bloquear o botão de ligar caso o LED esteja aceso, você pode definir o botão como `disabled` através deste código.

```js
function trigger(pin, status) {
    if (status == 0) {
        // LED está desligado
        $("ligar").attr("disabled", false);
        $("desligar").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        // LED está ligado
        $("ligar").attr("disabled", true);
        $("desligar").attr("disabled", false);
    }
}

$.get('read.php', {pin: 1}, function (data) {
    trigger(data.pin, data.status);
}, 'json');
```

Assim, quando o LED estiver ligado, somente o botão de desligar estará habilitado; e quando o LED estiver desligado, somente o botão de ligar estará habilitado. Se desejar fazer essa verificação constantemente, basta utilizar essa lógica em conjunto com a função `setInterval`.

**write.php**

Já o arquivo de escrita irá alterar o estado da aplicação, então deverá tratar uma requisição POST, recebendo como parâmetros o número do pino que deverá ser alterado e o seu novo estado. Como o comando de escrita não possui retornos, não precisamos definir o corpo da resposta HTTP, apenas o código do estado da resposta; isto é, uma resposta 200 se tudo ocorrer bem e uma 500 se der algo errado. Para este exemplo, irei considerar que se algo deu errado, alguma mensagem de erro seria exibida no terminal e, portanto, o `exec` retornaria algo diferente de uma *string* vazia.

```
<?php

// write.php

$pin = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pin', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$status = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'status', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

exec("gpio write {$pin} {$status}", $error);

if ($error == '') {
    http_response_code(200);
} else {
    http_response_code(500);
}
```

Com jQuery, você pode efetuar esta requisição com o `$.post`:

```js
$.post('write.php', {pin: 1, status: 1});
```

Assim, você pode utilizar tal código em conjunto com o evento *click* dos botões:

```js
$("#ligar").on("click", function (event) {
    $.post('write.php', {pin: 1, status: 1});
});

$("#desligar").on("click", function (event) {
    $.post('write.php', {pin: 1, status: 0});
});
```

Outros detalhes de implementação acredito que consiga fazer por conta apenas alterando a lógica apresentada aqui.

Comment: Usando a sua lógica para ler o status do pin, criei o ficheiro read.php com o seu código e inseri a função que desliga um dos botões dentro de uma aba de script javacript no <head> da minha página html mas não consigo obter resultado nenhum. Por outro lado já tenho um ficheiro em php que invoco quando a página faz load que responde com o status do pino para a variável data, que fazendo alert(data) posso ver o seu valor, existe a possibilidade de usar essa variável no seu código e assim resolver o problema. Obrigado pela ajuda e desculpa a falta de conhecimento!

Comment: A parte que lê o valor do php está a funcionar, se fizer um alert(data.status) nessa parte a página devolve o valor, não estou é a conseguir correr a função trigger, copiei o seu código para dentro de uma aba de script javacript.